# Android edittext loses and repeats texts received via TCP socket

Tags: android, sockets, tcp, android-edittext

I have a problem with a edittext in Android Studio.

Normally, log.d reports the messages received via TCP socket and
those appears in the textedit mySocketrx. When there is a fast
message burst log.d is still working fine but textedit loses and repeats
messages.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    final EditText mySocketrx = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Socketrx);

    new Thread(new Runnable() { // Client TCP socket thread
                public void run() {
                        try {
                            s = new Socket("192.168.1.161",6000);
                            p = new PrintStream(s.getOutputStream());
                            b = new BufferedReader ( new InputStreamReader( s.getInputStream() ) );
                        } catch(Exception ex) { }
            while (true) {
                            try {
                                    status = b.readLine();
                                    Log.d("DEBUG", status);
                                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                                        public void run() {
                                                mySocketrx.append(status + "\n");
                                        }
                                    } );
                            } catch(Exception ex) { }
                        }
        }
        }).start();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of append() use the setText() method.